# How to remove specific category in wordpress with php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the number of posts in each category in my site. 
So ,in functions.php,I add the part of 'add_filter'.But I don't want to show the number of posts in the case of headermenu in register_nav_menu(functions.php).
Please tell me how to remove the number of posts in the case of headermenu.
My functions.php is below.

```
        register_nav_menus( array(
           'headermenu' => 'ヘッダーナビ',
           'otoiawase' => 'お問い合わせ',
           '1footer' => '1列目フッター',
           '2footer' => '2列目フッター',
           'categoryzyuken' => '受験必勝テク',
           'categorycenter' => 'センター対策',
           'categorytwoexams' => '教科別ポイント',
           'categoryrest' => 'ちょっと一息',
       ) );
       add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects','my_nav_count');
       function my_nav_count($items){
           foreach ($items as $item){
             if(get_term($item->object_id,$item->object)->count > 0){
                $item->title .= " (". get_term($item->object_id,$item->object)->count .")";
            }else{
               $item->title .= get_term($item->object_id,$item->object)->count;
            }
           $args[] = $item;
          }
          return $args;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(is_category()) {
  add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects','my_nav_count');
  function my_nav_count($items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      if (get_term($item->object_id,$item->object)->count > 0) {
        $item->title .= " (". get_term($item->object_id,$item->object)->count .")";
      } else {
          $item->title .= get_term($item->object_id,$item->object)->count;
      }
      $args[] = $item;
    }
    return $args;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!But it doesn't work... the code removes the number of posts in all categories.

Comment: Try this is_category('your_category'); Let me know if it work.

Comment: Can u make a screenshot how it looks like now?

Comment: Your code doesn't work. So the screen in the case of 'with your code' looks  the screen in the case of  'without your code'.

Comment: Sorry, when I changed my code to your code in my functions.php, there is change that it  removes the number of posts in all custom nav menus . What information do you need?

Comment: Is the website somewhere online or is it local development? How many custom nav menus are there? Can I see what is going on through some screenshots?